# how I get the values of each row and column of a html table in c# codebehind which are dynamically generated by angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have a html table. the rows of this table are generated automatically by aangular js ng-repeat. I want to get values of each row and column of that table in c# codebehind.
Here is my aspx code:

```
<table id="stockTable" runat="server" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Quantity</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="aMedicine in medicines">
                            <td>{{aMedicine.Name}}</td>
                            <td>{{aMedicine.Quantity}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

and script is here:

```
<script>
    var myApplication = angular.module("myApp", []);
    var myArray = [];
    myApplication.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.medicines = [];
        $scope.AddMedicine = function (name, quantity) {
            $scope.medicines.push({ Name: name, Quantity: quantity });
            myArray = medicines;
        };
    });
</script>
```

how i get the added rows of the table in c# codebehind?

Comment: Rows and Columns don't have values.  Did you mean each [Cell (Table Data/td)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)?

Comment: yes. I want to catch all values of each cell. please help.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: no i am using angular js. but if needed i will use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about this in a reverse way.

You don't get values *out* of DOM to process data; instead, the values already exist in your ViewModel (in the controller), and the DOM is constructed based on them. In other words, the DOM is just some reflection of your ViewModel; the ViewModel is your source-of-truth for the data.

And so, if you have something like:

```
$scope.medicines = [...];
```

Then this is your ViewModel - just submit that.

If you are asking about how to determine which entries (that manifest themselves as rows, but that should not matter) were added vs. being originally retrieved from the backend, then you could just store the newly created elements in a temp array, until, say, the form is saved:

```
var newEntries = [];
$scope.AddMedicine = function (name, quantity) {
   var newEntry = { Name: name, Quantity: quantity };
   $scope.medicines.push(newEntry);
   newEntries.push(newEntry);
};

$scope.Save = function(){
   // ... Some code that submits to backend using MedicineSvc
   MedicineSvc.AddMedicine(newEntries)
      .then(function(){
         newEntries = [];
      });
}
```

Comment: I need the values of  $scope.medicines in c# codebehind. Actually user can add many items and finally s/he will be going to submit and only then all items will be saved in database.

Comment: Right. And so, your backend service (which I called `MedicineSvc`) would post these entries to the backend.

Comment: @AtikurRahman, did you understand the answer? Did it address your question?

Comment: I didn't want to use hidden field to store data. but i couldn't get any solution. so i solved this by using hidden field.